# Oncreateview is not calling after addtobackstack

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, fragment, android-fragmentactivity

As per fragment life cycle I am going like:

```
- Add fragment A + addToBackStack(null)
       |
- Add fragment B + addToBackStack(null)
```

and when I press back from B I expect Oncreateview should be call as per life cycle but it seems like : it just pop up back stage but no one method is call.so how can I identify back press in fragment A?

here is my simple code format:

```
// I am calling fragment like this way 

      Fragment fragmentb=new FragmentB();
            FragmentManager fragmentManager=getFragmentManager();
            FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction=fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
            fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.fragment,fragmentb).addToBackStack(null);
            fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

Comment: use fragmentTransaction.replace()  instead of fragmentTransaction.add

Comment: As your code, you are doing very fine. But instead of `null` in `addToBackStack` try to add some tag, placing null is not good practice. And instead of `adding` fragment try to `replace` it.

Comment: user setUserVisibleHint method in your fragment this method has a boolean parameter, if boolean params return true then this means user is viewing this fragment

Comment: thx every body but first I would like to clear that I don't want to replace the fragment, I want to add and then press back that time oncreateview should call as per rule.

Answer (score 0):

```
      Fragment fragmentb=new FragmentB();
            FragmentManager fragmentManager=getFragmentManager();
            FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction=fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
            fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment,fragmentb);
            fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
            fragmentTransaction.commit();
```